# Resolving External DNS from Azure Virtual Network

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines, azure

I've set up a virtual network in Windows Azure to host two Linux VMs (Centos / OpenLogic). I've registered a local DNS (local as in the cloud, not my personal network) inside the virtual network. I configured both VMs to use the virtual network and I am able to SSH into the boxes no problem. However, these boxes are not able to resolve external addresses (IP or DNS) and as a result, I am unable to use the package manager to install tools on these boxes. Is there a way that I can configure my virtual network to have an external gateway so that my VMs can access the outside world?

Comment: What kind of local dns are you using? Maybe you need to configure forwarders so they are able to resolve external adresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your local DNS server to forward queries to non-local addresses to external DNS server on the internet. [This article](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/09/19/setting-up-internal-dns-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/) provides instructions for how to achieve this on Ubuntu by forwarding unresolved addresses to Google's public DNS servers; you may be able to adapt the instructions for CentOS.